# Is there a way to load random content in a CSS square spinner?

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I want to load different images in a CSS square loader and I'm trying to do with flip animation and a :before selector.

Is there a way I can randomize content in the content tag?

```css
.loading{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#loader{
  -webkit-perspective: 120px;
  -moz-perspective: 120px;
  -ms-perspective: 120px;
  perspective: 120px;
}

#loader:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  animation: flip 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes flip {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg)  rotateX(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div >
        <div class="loading" id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You're expected to at least try and if you have problems, come back with specific questions.

Comment: You will need to do the random picking in JS.

Comment: Thanks, i got it. Through Math.random and the set Interval i was able to solve it

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer (and then accept it) so your question provides a benefit to future users facing the same issue.